# Adding Dynamic values to listview in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I want to add spinner values to listview on button click in fragment. Actually my screen contain two spinner and a listview. I just want to add spinner values to the list on button click. I have written some code for it but Iam getting null pointer exception in it. here is my code:

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_thirdswipe, container, false);
    arraylistAdd = new ArrayList<DeviceInfo>();
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spnDevice);

    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.spinner_items, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spnAction);
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.spinner_items, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    btnAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

    listOnAdd = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listDynamic);     
    deviceType = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    actionType = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Log.i("item", deviceType +" "+ actionType);
    adp=new CustomListDynamic(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_add_list,arraylistAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            info = new DeviceInfo();
            info.setAction(actionType);
            info.setDevice(deviceType);

            arraylistAdd.add(info);
            for(int i=0;i<arraylistAdd.size();i++){
                Log.i("itemArray", arraylistAdd.get(i).getDevice());
            }
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    listOnAdd.setAdapter(adp);

    return rootView;
}
```

My customAdpter class is following:

```
    public class CustomListDynamic  extends ArrayAdapter<DeviceInfo> {
Context context;
List<DeviceInfo> objects;   
int layoutResourceId;

    public CustomListDynamic(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            List<DeviceInfo> rowItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, rowItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        objects = rowItems;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
       private class ViewHolder {

            TextView txtDeviceType;
            TextView txtActionType;
        }
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            final DeviceInfo rowItem = getItem(position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_add_list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(); 
                holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceType);
                holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNumber);     
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                holder.txtDeviceType.setText(rowItem.getDevice());
                holder.txtActionType.setText(rowItem.getAction());
                Log.i("device set", rowItem.getDevice());
            return convertView;
        }          
}
```

Logcat:

```
 05-20 18:41:49.301: E/AndroidRuntime(2083):    at       android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439): java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at com.example.test.CustomListDynamic.getView(CustomListDynamic.java:66)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1141)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
 05-20 19:08:34.661: E/AndroidRuntime(2439):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
```

Please let me know the solution if anybody has..thanks

Comment: Can you post the logcat with the crash?

Comment: offcourse wait a sec..

Comment: @Howlin attached..please check

Comment: before down rate please let me know the solution.

Comment: @Howlin..no solution??

Comment: indicate line 66 @ `CustomListDynamic`

Comment: But I didn't find anything wrong in line66

Comment: what is in that? witch line is 66?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan..i need little help with something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your code with this,

```
public class CustomListDynamic  extends ArrayAdapter<DeviceInfo> {
Context context;
List<DeviceInfo> objects;   
int layoutResourceId;

    public CustomListDynamic(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            List<DeviceInfo> rowItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, rowItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        objects = rowItems;

    }

       private class ViewHolder {

            TextView txtDeviceType;
            TextView txtActionType;
        }

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            DeviceInfo rowItem = object.get(position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_add_list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(); 
                holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceType);
                holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNumber);     
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

              holder.txtDeviceType.setText(rowItem.getDevice());
              holder.txtActionType.setText(rowItem.getAction());
              Log.i("device set", rowItem.getDevice());
            return convertView;
        }          
     }
```

Changes:

remove `getItemId` and `getCount` because you don't needed on `ArrayAdapter`, you need those in `BaseAdapter` class, `super` on constructor class handle that

change

```
 final DeviceInfo rowItem = getItem(position);
```

to

```
 DeviceInfo rowItem = objects.get(position);
```

**Update**

if you have an error on

```
 "holder.txtActionType.setText(rowItem.getAction());"
```

3 possibility exists.

1- `holder.txtActionType` is null

2- `rowItem` is null

3- `rowItem.getAction()` is null

**your Problem:**

you not initialize `holder.txtActionType` in your code.

i think this is copy paste problem:

```
holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceType);
holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNumber);
```

both line you initialize `txtDeviceType` one of them must be `holder.txtActionType`

Comment: Object is same as objects..which i used as ""List<deviceinfo>objects"

Comment: its ok...no it didn't..i recount the line number again and found that line 66 is "holder.txtActionType.setText(rowItem.getAction());"

Comment: see my Edit and fix your problem

Comment: thanks a lot..i have one more problem..please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773829/swipe-view-with-different-actionbar-items-in-each-swipe-fragment

Answer (score 0):

when you are click on button at that time you have to set data for the adapter. Then you have to write notifidatasetchange method.

In your case you will get rowItem value is null that means   `List<DeviceInfo> objects`;  is also get null object value.

now Your code is

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_thirdswipe, container, false);
    arraylistAdd = new ArrayList<DeviceInfo>();
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spnDevice);

    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.spinner_items, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spnAction);
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.spinner_items, spinnerArray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    btnAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

    listOnAdd = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listDynamic);     
    deviceType = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    actionType = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Log.i("item", deviceType +" "+ actionType);
    adp=new CustomListDynamic(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_add_list,arraylistAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            info = new DeviceInfo();
            info.setAction(actionType);
            info.setDevice(deviceType);

            arraylistAdd.add(info);
            for(int i=0;i<arraylistAdd.size();i++){
                Log.i("itemArray", arraylistAdd.get(i).getDevice());
            }
            **adp.setObjectValue(info);** //set value of your object from here
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    listOnAdd.setAdapter(adp);

    return rootView;
}
```

And your Custome Adapter class will be like This

```
 public class CustomListDynamic  extends ArrayAdapter<DeviceInfo> {
Context context;
List<DeviceInfo> objects;   
int layoutResourceId;

    public CustomListDynamic(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            List<DeviceInfo> rowItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, rowItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        objects = rowItems;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public void setObjectValue(List<DeviceInfo> info){
       objects=info;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
       private class ViewHolder {

            TextView txtDeviceType;
            TextView txtActionType;
        }
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            final DeviceInfo rowItem = getItem(position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_add_list, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(); 
                holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceType);
                holder.txtDeviceType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMobileNumber);     
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                holder.txtDeviceType.setText(rowItem.getDevice());
                holder.txtActionType.setText(rowItem.getAction());
                Log.i("device set", rowItem.getDevice());
            return convertView;
        }          
}
```